# How to Redirect PHP login to log user Directly into ASPX site?

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, redirect, authentication

Two different sites one PHP and the other ASPX. Problem is on the PHP site the login takes the user to our login page - it doesn't directly log the user into the password protected area. We want to user to login *directly* into our site from the Clients site.

Our regular login:

```
<form id="autolog" action="https://www.website.com/AutoLogin.aspx" method="get" name="autolog">
```

and `<img onclick=" submitBtn();" src="img/btnSubmit.gif" alt="Submit" height="23" width="73" />` (and login code -see below) works on HTML sites (working as in user enters login and password and is taken *directly* into the password protected area.

However when I put the Autologin.aspx in menu.php and the accompanying JavaScript into javascript folder the user enters name&password and is taken to our login page :( - and is not logged *directly* into our site. And just noticed that clicking on the login button opens our aspx login page which means the dropped in code has no effect of recognizing the user/pass. It's just a dog & pony show with no javascript engagement.

How to get the PHP site to recognize the user/password and log directly into our aspx site?

Here is the original snippet of code from menu.php on the client site:

```
>><?php 
include("./login/database.php");
?>
<link href="/_stylesheets/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/_includes/js/m.js"></script>
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="login">

    <?
    //var_dump($_SESSION['logged_in']);
if($session->logged_in){
    print("<a href='process.php'> Logout </a> | <a href='/?sec=login&sub=myaccount'> My Account </a>");
}else{

    ?>
    <span>Login in and submit work and check status online</span>
    <span> |</span> USER <input type="text" name="user" class="medium" maxlength="30">
    Password <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="medium" maxlength="30"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="sublogin" id="button" value="sublogin"/> 
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="button" value="LOGIN" class="inputbtn"/>
<? } ?>
```

Here is the modified code supposed to Log User Directly in:

```
<link href="/_stylesheets/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_includes/js/global.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/_includes/js/m.js"></script>
<body onload="pageLoad();">
<form id="autolog" action="https://www.website.com/AutoLogin.aspx" method="get" name="autolog">

<?
    //var_dump($_SESSION['logged_in']);
if($session->logged_in){
    print("<a href='process.php'> Logout </a> | <a href='/?sec=login&sub=myaccount'> My Account </a>");
}else{

    ?>
    <span>&nbsp; Login | &nbsp;<a href="https://www.website.com/default.aspx?psid=175&pstype=st&psonly=1&target=home">SIGN UP HERE</a></span>
    <span> |</span> User <input type="text" name="user" class="medium" maxlength="30">
    Password <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="medium" maxlength="30"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="sublogin" id="button" value="sublogin"/> 
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="button" value="LOGIN" class="inputbtn"/>
    <span><a href="https://www.website.com/forgotpass.aspx?psid=175pstype=st&psonly=1&target=home">Forgot your password?</a></span>
<? } ?>
```

Where do I put - `<img onclick=" submitBtn();" src="img/btnSubmit.gif" alt="Submit" height="23" width="73" />`

It is as simple as putting - submitBtn(); -(activates the java) in the right spot? Where does it go? I've tried it everywhere. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer weeks ago - my question was probably somewhat convoluted but here's the answer - :

Login | SIGN UP
     | User 
    Password 
    
    FORGOT PASSWORD?